# How can I return the variable color value so that I can apply it in an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Below you can see my incomplete code. The first block of code can be used to have a live update of a color value that is currently being applied to an empty div. I want to be able to save the selected value to be used in an onclick event on the table.

I want to be able to set the color by using the RGB sliders. Then click on a td element where the value can be added to the backgroundColor. And to be able to repeat this action whilst the already called onclick events will remain the previously selected color.

Any help is very much appreciated.

```js
var input = document.querySelectorAll("input");
for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    input[i].addEventListener("input", function(){
        var red = document.getElementById("red").value,
            green = document.getElementById("green").value,
            blue = document.getElementById("blue").value;
        var display = document.getElementById("display");
        display.style.background = "rgb(" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + ")"; 
    });
}
// HOW DO I RETURN THIS VALUE TO BE USED IN THE NEXT LINE OF CODE? THE VALUE WOULD REPLACE "myColor()"

window.onload = function() {
    var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("tableBox");
    
    for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        cells[i].onclick = function() {
            cells[i].style.backgroundColor = myColor();
        }
    }  
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: courier, arial, serif;
}

/* ////////// ////////// */

.container {
    display: flex;
}

.left {
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid #232323;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.right {
    flex: 1;
}

#display {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #f00;
}

/* ///// ///// */

.grid {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 20px;
}

table {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

td {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link href="css/T4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
                <p>Red</p><input type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" id="red" value="255"/>
                <br/><br/>
                <p>Green</p><input type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" id="green" value="0"/>
                <br/><br/>
                <p>Blue</p><input type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" id="blue" value="0"/>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div id="display">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid">
        <table id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <td class="tableBox"></td>
                <td class="tableBox"></td>
                <td class="tableBox"></td>
                <td class="tableBox"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tableBox"></td>
                <td class="tableBox"></td>
                <td class="tableBox"></td>
                <td class="tableBox"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tableBox"></td>
                <td class="tableBox"></td>
                <td class="tableBox"></td>
                <td class="tableBox"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tableBox"></td>
                <td class="tableBox"></td>
                <td class="tableBox"></td>
                <td class="tableBox"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="js/T4.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for?

```
function myColor() {
    var red = document.getElementById("red").value,
    green = document.getElementById("green").value,
    blue = document.getElementById("blue").value;

    return "rgb(" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + ")";
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to save the value, since it is saved as the background color of the `'display'` element.

I suggest you use the following '`window.onload`':

```
window.onload = function() {
    var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("tableBox");

    for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        cells[i].onclick = function() {
            var display = document.getElementById("display");
            cells[i].style.backgroundColor = display.style.backgroundColor;
        }
    }  
}
```